# Javascript mapping array with an object

Tags: javascript

I have a question about the Javascript mapping array with an object.

cart.json:

```
{ "products": [ { "id": "0.17912240212736852","qty": 1 } ], "totalPrice": 336 }
```

Here is my code:

```
let cart = { products: [], totalPrice: 0 };

const a = cart.products.map(product => {
    product.id === id ? { ...product, qty: product.qty + 1 } : product;
});

// Undefined
console.log(a);
```

The Result I want is to add 1 to the qty

Even if I tried to do the following:

```
const a = cart.products.map(product => {
    console.log(product);
});

// Undefined
console.log(a);
```

Can any explain what is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: your arrow function isn't return anything. Use `return` to return the expression, or remove the function body `{}` to implicitly return.

Comment: you need to `return` if you use map

Comment: A `.forEach()` with a simple `+= 1` would be easier (unless you really need a copy of `cart.products`)

Comment: Thanks! I always forget to return when I do mapping....... I will try forEach() as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything, try wrapping the {} with () or directly write return,

Like this:

```
let cart = { products: [], totalPrice: 0 };

const a = cart.products.map(product => {
    return product.id === id ? { ...product, qty: product.qty + 1 } : product;
});

// Undefined
console.log(a);
```